# Money limit to pay tax for Patreon

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

This might be a bit out of place, but I just joined Patreon as a creator and I'm not that sure about the tax requirements.  How much income do I have to be making to have to pay tax?

What if I made, say 1k in profit, but I use it to be a patron for other people.  Would I still need to send in a 1099?

Comment: What country are you in? Do you have any other income or is this it?

Comment: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/am-i-required-to-file-a-form-1099-or-other-information-return

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the US, you legally must file taxes on any income whatsoever.  How much you will pay in taxes, if any, will depend on your total taxable income.

Now, for small transactions, the payments are often not reported to the IRS so some people do not file or pay.  The threshold at which they payer is required to send a 1099 to the IRS is $600.  Patreon considers each donation a separate transaction and therefore does not send a 1099 to the IRS [unless you make more than $20,000](https://patreon.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207099566-Will-I-receive-a-1099-form-) in a calendar year.  If they do not report it, the IRS will not know about it unless they audit you or something.

However, you are technically and legally responsible to report income whether the IRS knows about it or not.

-------- EDIT -------

Note that the payer files a 1099, not the recipient. In order to report your patreon income you will either use schedule C or add it to the amount on 1040 line 21 ("other income") depending on whether you consider this a business or a hobby.  If it's a business and it's a lot of money you should consider sending in quarterly payments using a 1040-ES in order to avoid a penalty for too little withholding.